# Add next element to current selection

Tags: jquery

How do you add the next element onto the current selection stack?

I tried this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$('.p-tag').add($(this).next());
```

HTML:

```
<div class="p-tag"></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Where is this code `$('.p-tag').add($(this).next());`, mean scope for this.

Comment: I'm afraid, can you explain "current selection stack"?

Comment: @RupamDatta The selection stack is everything that you select with a jQuery chain.

Answer (score 1):

use `.add()` with correct selector:

```
 $('.p-tag').add( $('.p-tag').next());
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z75Ge/)**

Comment: I don't want to add it to the HTML, I want to add it to my jQuery selection.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[.addBack()](http://api.jquery.com/addback/)** here instead:

> Add the previous set of elements on the stack to the current set,
>   optionally filtered by a selector

```
$('.p-tag').next().addBack()
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LeNtA/)**

Comment: This is something to what I'm looking for. Will accept unless someone provides a solution where `next` is added to the current set, and not the other way around :)

Comment: Actually, your code is ok, just the scope problem with `$(this)`. You can do like this instead: `$('.p-tag').add( $('.p-tag').next());`

Answer (score 0):

`this` does not refer to the previous selector in this context so you need to use the original selector to find the next elements:

```
$('.p-tag').add($('.p-tag').next());
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/KH7kJ/

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
$('.p-tag').add($('.p-tag').next()).css('color','green');
```

Courtesy Felix,